# Type Converter in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have gone through this article but still i am not very much clear about Type Converter and its usage.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx

Can anyone please explain in what it is and what can be done with it in WPF.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx

Comment: Good blog post: http://windowsclient.net/blogs/rob_relyea/archive/2008/04/10/strings-to-things-or-how-xaml-interprets-attribute-values.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example - when you set a background property in XAML, you can write "Red", in code behind you cannnot just give the Background property the string "Red" because its type is Brush.
WPF uses a type converter to convert from string to brush.

Comment: Doesn't really have anything to do with databinding.

Comment: how and why should I use converters without data binding ?

Comment: [Type converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) != [Value converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx). They are completely different and the former has nothing to do with data binding.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a property that is not of type `string`, but you need to set it from a XAML attribute, you need to convert the `string` specified in XAML to the target property type. Hence, type converters.

Answer (score 4):

[WPF 4.5 Unleashed](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17939566-wpf-4-5-unleashed) has an extensive introduction to [XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/fundamentals/xaml) declarative language. Some pages can be read on [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books/about/WPF_4_5_Unleashed.html?id=ubgRAAAAQBAJ). I'm now refering to [page 26](https://books.google.com/books?id=ubgRAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA26).

If we want to specify the background color of a `Button` object (actually [`Control.Background`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.background?view=netframework-4.8)), this is what we need to do as long as type converters are not *explicitly* added (by Microsoft) to the classes we use:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                <Color A="255" R="255" G="255" B="255" />
            </SolidColorBrush.Color>
        </Button.Background>
    </SolidColorBrush>
</Button>
```

In this declaration,

```
<Button.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush>
```

means we create an instance of `SolidColorBrush` and assign it to `Button.Background` property, which type is [`Brush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.background?view=netframework-4.8), an abstract type.

Similarly,

```
<SolidColorBrush.Color>
    <Color A="255" R="255" G="255" B="255" />
```

means we create an instance of `Color` with corresponding properties, and assign it to [`SolidColorBrush.Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.background?view=netframework-4.8) which type is [`Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color?view=netframework-4.8).

A first simplification is possible by using a explicit converter able to understand that the string literal `White` when provided as the content of a `Color` XML element must be converted into a `Color` instance obtained with [`Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color.fromargb?view=netframework-4.8). This simplification now allow us to write:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                White
            </SolidColorBrush.Color>
        </Button.Background>
    </SolidColorBrush>
</Button>
```

The possibility to use such converter has been explicitly added to the declaration of `Color` structure by specifying a [type converter attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute?view=netframework-4.8):

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ColorConverter))]
public struct Color : IFormattable, IEquatable<Color>
```

The converter is [ColorConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.colorconverter?view=netframework-4.8).

Let's push that a step further, and add a type converter on `Brush`, the type of [Control.Background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.background?view=netframework-4.8).

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(BrushConverter))]
public abstract class Brush : Animatable, IFormattable, DUCE.IResource
```

This converter will replace a valid string literal content with a `SolidColorBrush` instance and now allows:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Background>
        White
    </SolidColorBrush>
</Button>
```

This is the mechanism behind simplifications allowed by XAML when interpreting the XML content. A last simplification allowed by XAML: We can use the attribute syntax of XAML rather than the element syntax:

```
<Button Background="White" />
```

Wow! we started with 9 lines of code, and ended with only one!

A last word on how a XML element string literal content is interpreted (still from the same book):

> **XAML Processing Rules for Object Element Children**
>
> You’ve now seen the three types of children for object elements. To
>   avoid ambiguity, any valid XAML parser or compiler follows these rules
>   when encountering and interpreting child elements:
>
> 1. If the type implements IList, call IList.Add for each child.
> 2. Otherwise, if the type implements IDictionary, call IDictionary.Add for each child, using the x:Key attribute value for the key and the
>      element for the value. (Although XAML2009 checks IDictionary before
>      IList and supports other collection interfaces, as described earlier.)
> 3. Otherwise, if the parent supports a content property (indicated by System.Windows.Markup.ContentPropertyAttribute) and the type of the
>      child is compatible with that property, treat the child as its value.
> 4. Otherwise, if the child is plain text and a type converter exists to 
>      transform the child into the parent type (and no properties are set 
>      on the parent element), treat the child as the input to the type
>      converter and use the output as the parent object instance.
> 5. Otherwise, treat it as unknown content and potentially raise an error.

To answer your question about converter benefit in a different way: This benefit comes from rule 4 above.